# At what size is *.xsession-errors* turned into *.xsession-errors.old*?

Tags: logs, logrotate

My *.xsession-errors* file is growing steadily (which is apparently a common phenomenon) and not unexpected (I still have to address some issues on my system).

**Question:** Is there a specific threshold when the system saves *.xsession-errors* as *.xsession-errors.old* and starts a new file?  And if there is some kind of logrotate for it, can this limit be changed and how?

*.xsession-errors* has now the size of about 1.2 GB and I think this should be enough.

Thanks for your advice!

Comment: I don't think that it's ever turned into an `~/.xsession-errors.old`. Try adding a `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/10trim-xsession-errors` file with this content: `err=$HOME/.xsession-errors; tail -n2000 "$err" > "$err.new" && mv "$err.new" "$err" && exec >>"$err" 2>&1`. Adjust the `2000` to how many lines you want to keep from the output from the old sessions and the stuff run in this session before that script. Not giving you a complete answer because I'm using a highly modified X11 setup, and I have very little love for those initialization scripts ;-)

Comment: That would probably also works if added to the per-user `~/.xsessionrc`; just try this first.

Comment: Thanks, @mosvy, I created the aforementioned file with said content and adjusted the -n to 1000000 (the current .xsession-errors has 6652785 lines and is still adding).  However, I am not sure how your suggestion works, I don't see any difference.

Comment: Try with something small like 25 lines, and login & out a couple of times to check if it really works ;-)

Comment: Okay, but 1. should I replace the old .xsession-errors file?; 2. is the new file executed by itself or do I have to activate it somehow?; 3. are actually the old logs saved?  --  Sorry, I am not very familiar with Linux and bash syntax

Comment: 1. no it should truncate it automatically. 2. the `/etc/X11/Xsession` script should run in order anything it finds under `/etc/X11/Xsession.d` and `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/40x11-common_xsessionrc` should run the user's `~/.xsessionrc`. Check with debugging `echo`s if that's the really the case on your system. 3. It's up to how much of the old log you want to keep -- with `tail -n 1000000` will be of course quite slow. Better try something reasonable like 1000 or 2000 lines.

Comment: I would like to keep the old logs as, at least at the moment, disk space is not of an issue.  It would let me know over time how many of the bugs I could address and fix.  If everything gets clogged older logs can be removed manually anyway.  The easiest thing would be to just add the extension `.old` to the end of the file, however, since it is fed by continually I am not sure if this is a good idea.

Comment: Or use tail with a byte count instead of a line count which will work instantenously no matter how big it is -- the only problem would be that the 1st line may be truncated. You can of course do whatever you like with *.old or numeric backups, the problem is to integrate it with the startup scripts, and I think that my suggestion does for that.

Comment: @mosvy:  okay, it truncates the file but without keeping the older entries

Comment: Create an `~/old-sessions` directory, and from an `Xsession.d` startup script or `~/.xsessionrc`, run `mv "$HOME/.xsession-errors" "$HOME/old-xsessions/$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)"` instead of truncating it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GG, look in `/etc/logrotate.d` 
there may be a logrotate file doing the work and then you can manipulate the number of days and file size to rotate and many other things.

File name probably called xsession or similar. 
Let us know what you find in /etc/logrotate.d

> Added after Edit

If you find nothing you could create a new logrotate

You can add a file to create a new logrotate in /etc/logrotate.d
Here is something I have used variations of many times. 
copy this to /etc/logrotate.d/xsessionerrors (new file)

```
#Rotates "$HOME/.xsession-errors" daily if not empty AND over 20M. 
#Creates a file as root and compresses it with gz 
#only saves 5 copies or previous day of logs. 
$HOME/.xsession-errors {
missingok 
notifempty 
compress 
size 20M 
daily 
create 0600 root root 
rotate 5
}
```

Logrotate has many variables but this will get you going with some obvious settings you can tweek.

Comment: I cannot comment on others posts yet due to rating.

Comment: Thanks, @Mark Stewart, `logrotate` is installed and apparently works fine with `syslog` and other logs;  however, `.xsession-errors` does not seem to be covered by it.  `/etc/logrotate.d/` contains only files for _alternatives, apt, aptitude, btmp, cups-daemon, dpkg, ppp, rsyslog, speech-dispatcher, unattended-upgrades_ as well as _wtmp_.

Comment: I tried to upvote your answer, but got the message _Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score._  Sorry about that!  --  EDIT: Now it worked!

Comment: sorry I could never get the code format in the comment above.

Comment: Yes, formating comments seems to be a little tricky in stackexchange.  Maybe you want to put it in a separate answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Great G. I will move it to my original reply. (per the site suggestion)

Comment: for some reason I don't get it working;  even if I run manually `logrotate -v /etc/logrotate.d/xsession-errors` I do get the message _error: /etc/logrotate.d/xsession-errors:1 lines must begin with a keyword or a filename (possibly in double quotes)_;  even if I copy a working config file from the same location and only change its name and target, logrotate gives the same complaint

Comment: `cat /var/lib/logrotate/status` shows it did something, but there is no rotated log

Comment: you may have special characters in the file. Logrotate will not work with CRLF or other special characters. Did you edit this file in VIM (any linux command line editor) or a Windows app? Try 
`dos2unix -b /etc/logrotate.d/xsession-errors` to strip the special chars.

Comment: Yes, that was it!  I had used a plain text editor (KWrite or Kate) and saved it now via nano.  Despite the identical content the filesize was reduced by 5 bytes (I wonder why exactly 5 bytes as the file has 7 lines).  Anyway, everything works fine now, thanks a lot!